# Black incomplete contents after image resized in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics

I'm using gfx.DrawImage to generate thumbnails of user-uploaded images on my Azure hosted web site.

Once every now and then, one of the thumbnails randomly contains a large black section, almost as if the resizing was interrupted and not completed. If I re-generate the same image again, it's almost always generated perfectly fine (without the black section) upon the second try. So it's a very random issue that only happens occasionally and can't be consistently reproduced.

Here is an example:

**Original image:**

```
http://naturemap.blob.core.windows.net/userimages-splash/30161.jpg
```

**Affected thumbnail:**

```
http://canberranaturemap.org/ImgSrvr?Id=30161&No=1&W=160&MinH=120&MaxH=120
```

This is the code I'm using which works 99.9% of the time!

```
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(originalImage, FinalWidthPx, HeightPx);

using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    gfx.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
    gfx.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
}
```

Comment: Are there any `OutOfMemoryException` being risen at all? Do you have any try/catch which doesn't rise any errors and might be hiding them (or other exceptions)?

Comment: Hi Jcl - No not that I can tell. I just double checked and I have no try/catch statements anywhere and I've never seen a web page crash during image processing. I also checked the Azure logs and it says it's had no HTTP Server errors. Hmm..

Comment: I don't know then, you might try to do some stress testing on this, say feeding a few thousand images (for example, make a test original image that doesn't have any black and check for some pixels at the bottom of resulting image to be black) and see if the frequency of the problem appearing is not "that" random or something like that.

Comment: (btw, as a side note -and not relevant to the problem-, if you are using `System.Drawing`, and doing no further processing than scaling, check [Image.GetThumbnailImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than drawing yourself to a new bitmap using `Graphics`)

Comment: Thanks. I tried Image.GetThumbnailImage() and got it all working, but the resulting image quality is extremely low and very grainy/blurry. I think it's only good for very small dimension images. Your load testing idea has merit, maybe this issue is related to threading/contentions on the server even when the same library/code is being called by simultaneous requests...?

Comment: Based on the code you posted, I'd say no (but you never know)... there might be other code around that could be giving problems. Maybe instead of working with the image directly, you could offload the thumbnail generation to a queue (with proper locking) so that graphics operations are being called synchronously on the server? Just giving wild broad ideas to try here.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your lead and setup a little load testing page which basically tried to request 500 dynamically re-sized versions of the same image all at the same time :)

Boom!! I was able to reproduce the issue repeatedly by refreshing that page. On different page loads, it affected different sized images every time. That helped me realise that it is definitely load or resource/contention related.

Then I reviewed the code for my image resizing routine )which I'm fairly proud of because it goes through multiple parses and intelligently crops images when it needs to while also maintaining the correct proportions etc).

I digress, but every time I was doing another crop or resizing operation on the image, I was re-saving it and re-fetching it another time to and from the Azure Blob storage service. So for a typical given image, I was saving and fetching the image to Azure Blob disk up to say 3 times during the re-processing routine. I realised that was definitely hitting the IO too hard, so I re-factored a few things and did it all in memory and only saved back to the Azure Blob service a single time at the end once the image was in it's very final state.

Wha lah no more random black line issue! All resolved.

Many thanks for the idea Jcl. I should mark this as your answer.